# How do I only allow VPN traffic when connected to an unsecured wireless AP?

Tags: windows-7, security, wireless-networking, vpn

When I'm connected to an unsecured wireless AP (coffee shop for example), I want to limit my computer to only sending traffic through my VPN connection. *When I'm connected* to the VPN, this is generally the case. However, occasionally the VPN will disconnect if there's a wireless dropout, etc. In this case, I don't want the computer to silently start sending unencrypted packets over the air.

The rule is: **If connected through an unsecured wireless connection then only allow VPN traffic.** When I connect to the VPN, obviously other traffic would automatically be allowed because it acts as an additional WAN connection.

Operating system is Windows 7 x64 RTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a tolerable solution to this problem by setting up "Firewall user profiles" in ESET Smart Security. I have a "Home" profile, a "Mobile" profile, and an "Insecure" profile. It's set to default to the Insecure profile unless I join a network that I've manually configured on one of the other profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for the same thing, sadly "firewall" is the best thing i found so far, too.

Another suggestions was to have a broken default route and a single working route to the VPN server in the wlan adapter, so the only thing that works by default is contacting the VPN Server, when the connection is established, the vpn sets the new default (over the vpn device)

ps) this seems like something that not many people are aware off -> that all those nifty autorun/autoconnect apps might be spewing their cleartext data over the wifi until the VPN is (re)connected...