# How to make Windows 8.1 auto-connect to a VPN if connecting to an unsecure WiFi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, vpn

When connecting to an unsecure WiFi network, is there any chance to force Windows to make sure it is connected to one of my selected VPNs before allowing any other traffic to pass through that WiFi connection?

I'm not looking for [answers like this](https://superuser.com/a/737800/267867) where it takes some time between the establishment of the WiFi connection and the establishment of the VPN connection. Instead, no application (with the exception of the VPN connection application) should be able to send or receive packets as long as there is no secure connection.

Preferrably this should work without having to install other tools like it was required in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/162430/267867).

Comment: I dont think Windows has such flexible option, what about if vpn connection is failed? Should it disconnect from the unsecure wifi network?

Comment: In such a case it should simply not let any traffic pass (of course with the exception of VPN traffic between my computer and the VPN server). Therefore it doesn't really matter if it stayed connected or even disconnected automatically.